# Displaying javascript variable in php not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code that incorporate javascript inside php code. The problem is the variable "i" is not properly display and it is interpret as "('calendarRandom" + i + "')" but I want to be is 
"('calendarRandom0')", "('calendarRandom1')" and so on...

Here is my php code

```
 $ret .= "
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function randomCheck()
 {
    var i;
    var optionIndex = document.getElementById('randomSelect').value;
    for (i=0; i<optionIndex; i++) {
        var calendarRandom = 'calendarRandom' + i;
        document.getElementById('calendarRandom\" + i + \").style.display = 'block';

    }
 }
 </script>";
```

Can anyone know how to figure out this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? All you have posted is you declaring a PHP variable that, as far as PHP is concerned, is nothing more than a string of text

Comment: Why are you doing `'calendarRandom\" + i + \"`?  What's with the mix of single and double quotes in there?  This code is a JavaScript syntax error and won't run.  Also, didn't you ***already*** append `i` to `'calendarRandom'` (`var calendarRandom = 'calendarRandom' + i;`)?  Why not just do: `document.getElementById(calendarRandom)`?

Comment: document.getElementById(calendarRandom) is not working.. I don't know why the variable i is not interpreted properly in php. but when you use alert(i) it's work!

Comment: @user1852837: What do you mean by "not interpreted properly in php"?  PHP just reads this as a string.  That's it.  It does *not* "interpret" it.  PHP runs on the ***server***  It just creates/prints the HTML and JavaScript for the client to  run.  When the browser (client) runs the JavaScript, PHP is long since finished.  What's the issue here?  P.S. What does `alert(calendarRandom)` show you?  How are you calling `randomCheck()`?  What's `randomSelect`?

Comment: Can you guide me how to make like this: ('calendarRandom0'), ('calendarRandom1'), ('calendarRandom2') etc.. still inside the variable in php ($ret);

Comment: @user1852837: You can't.  Your `for` loop depends on a JavaScript variable.  You ***cannot*** mix PHP and JavaScript like you want.  PHP runs on the *server*.  It *generates* the JavaScript for the browser to run.  Then it exits.  You cannot do it any other way than what you have.  What's wrong with `document.getElementById(calendarRandom)`?  What do you see when you do `alert(calendarRandom)`?

Comment: check the answer. it should give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ret .= "
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function randomCheck()
 {
    var i;
    var optionIndex = document.getElementById('randomSelect').value;
    for (i=0; i<optionIndex; i++) {
        var calendarRandom = 'calendarRandom' + i;
        document.getElementById('calendarRandom' + i).style.display = 'block';

    }
 }
 </script>";

 echo $ret;


 ?>
```

This does it :)

Comment: Even better, `document.getElementById(calendarRandom)` :-)